# After duplicating event, creating a new location updates the parent event location

Tags: civievent, location

I duplicated an event, and then, on that new event, clicked "Create New Location." The location saved successfully, but the old event and all events created from it had their locations updated as well. Why?

Comment: This seems to be a core bug when a event is cloned. Can you please create at issue on https://issues.civicrm.org/ and submit a PR to fix the above bug?

Comment: We've seen a plethora of issues with event locations, including:

Comment: Sorry - hit enter instead of Shift+Enter in my comment above ... here goes the whole comment:

We've seen a plethora of issues with event locations, including:
- existing location gets updated instead of a new one created (when using "Create new")
- coordinates do not populate correctly in the d/b (if already exist, they don't get changed; if they don't exist, they're null after save)

Has an issue been logged? I don't see it in Github or Jira, but thought I'd ask here first. Thx

Comment: No, I haven't been able to log an issue yet. I tried to create an account and was told I'd get a confirmation email once the staff had reviewed my application but I haven't received anything yet.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a fix will be included in 5.5.0

https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/255